# Displaying a fruit in snake game

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a snake game in which if the snake eats the first fruit and in 2 seconds eats the second fruit then it's score multiplied by 2. If the snake eats the second fruit in 1 second then the score is multiplied by 3. If the snake eats the second fruit in 3 seconds then the score is increased just by 1 and so on ... But i can't display the fruit. I declared the fruit in this function

```
void make_stage() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
        gotoxy(i, 1);
        printf("#");
        gotoxy(1, i);
        printf("#");
        gotoxy(17, i);
        printf("#");
        gotoxy(i, 17);
        printf("#");
    }
    x = height / 2;
    y = width / 2;
label1:
    fruitx = rand() % 20;
    if (fruitx == 0)
        goto label1;
label2:
    fruity = rand() % 20;
    if (fruity == 0)
        goto label2;
    score = 0;
    if (i == fruitx)
        printf("*");
}
```

Does anybody know why the fruit is not visible? Thanks!

This is my whole code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i, j, height = 17, width = 17;
int score;
int x, y, fruitx, fruity, flag;

typedef struct RECORD {
    char name[100];
    int score;
    int time;
}record; //Name, Points,Time

record nowrec;

void gotoxy(int x, int y);          //Input location
void make_stage();                  //stage
int getCommand();                   // Keyboard input
void gameover();                    //Gameover screen
void startscr();                    //Start screen
void snake_move();                  //Snake movements
void rank_call();                   //Displaying rank
void rankrecord();                  //personal records
void cursor(int i);             //커서 상태 변경
void time_show();

int main(void) {
    startscr();
    return 0;
}
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    COORD pos = { 30 + x * 2, 10 + y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}

void make_stage() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
        gotoxy(i, 1);
        printf("#");
        gotoxy(1, i);
        printf("#");
        gotoxy(17, i);
        printf("#");
        gotoxy(i, 17);
        printf("#");
    }
    x = height / 2;
    y = width / 2;
label1:
    fruitx = rand() % 20;
    if (fruitx == 0)
        goto label1;
label2:
    fruity = rand() % 20;
    if (fruity == 0)
        goto label2;
    score = 0;
    if (i == fruitx)
        printf("*");
}

int getCommand() {
    if (_kbhit()) {
        return _getch();
    }
    return -1;
}

void cursor(int i) {
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo = { 0, };
    cursorInfo.dwSize = 1;
    cursorInfo.bVisible = i;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &cursorInfo);
}

void rank_call() {
    FILE* rank;
    char reading[100];
    if (fopen_s(&rank, "rank.txt", "r") != 0) printf("no record\n");
    else {
        printf("\n");
        while ((fgets(reading, 100, rank) != NULL)) printf("%s", reading);
        fclose(rank);
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void rankrecord() {
    printf("\npress enter to proceed...\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("press r to record your ranking...");
    char input = _getch();
    if (input == 'r') {
        FILE* rank;
        fopen_s(&rank, "rank.txt", "a");
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("enter your name: ");
        gets_s(nowrec.name, sizeof(nowrec.name));
        fprintf(rank, "%s %d %d\n", nowrec.name, nowrec.score, nowrec.time);
        fclose(rank);
    }
}

void startscr()
{
    system("mode con cols=100 lines=40");
start:
    system("cls");
    printf("   ******   **    *       *      *    *  ******           ******      *        **    **    ******   \n");
    printf("   *        * *   *      * *     *   *   *                *          * *      *  *  *  *   *        \n");
    printf("   ******   *  *  *     *****    ****    ******           *  ***    *****     *  *  *  *   ******   \n");
    printf("        *   *   * *    *     *   *   *   *                *    *   *     *   *    **    *  *        \n");
    printf("   ******   *    **   *       *  *    *  ******           ******  *       *  *    **    *  ******   \n");
    printf("\npress s to start game\n");
    printf("press r to see ranking\n");
    printf("press x to exit\n:");
    char input = _getch();
    if (input == 's') {
        system("cls");
        cursor(0);
        make_stage();
        snake_move();
    }
    else if (input == 'r') {
        rank_call();
        printf("press enter to continue...");
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        goto start;
    }
    else if (input == 'x') exit(0);
    else {
        printf("wrong input\n");
        printf("press enter to continue...");
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        goto start;
    }
}

void gameover() {
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("        ******      *        **    **    ******            ****   *       *  ******   *****         \n");
    printf("        *          * *      *  *  *  *   *                *    *   *     *   *        *    *        \n");
    printf("        *  ***    *****     *  *  *  *   ******           *    *    *   *    ******   *****         \n");
    printf("        *    *   *     *   *    **    *  *                *    *     * *     *        *    *        \n");
    printf("        ******  *       *  *    **    *  ******            ****       *      ******   *     *      \n");
    cursor(1);
    rankrecord();
}

void snake_move() {
    int x = 9, y = 9;
    int x1 = 8, y1 = 9;
    int x2 = 7, y2 = 9;
    int x3 = 6, y3 = 9;
    int x4 = 5, y4 = 9;
    char dir = 'd';
    char input = 'e';
    gotoxy(x, y);
    printf("a");
    gotoxy(x1, y1);
    printf("*");
    gotoxy(x2, y2);
    printf("*");
    gotoxy(x3, y3);
    printf("*");
    gotoxy(x4, y4);
    printf("*");
    while (1) {
        input = _getch();
        if ((dir == 'w' && input != 's') || (dir == 'a' && input != 'd') || (dir == 's' && input != 'w') || (dir == 'd' && input != 'a')) {
            if (input == 'w') {
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf(" ");
                x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                y = y - 1;
                if (y == 1) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                gotoxy(x, y);
                printf("a");
                gotoxy(x1, y1);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x2, y2);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x3, y3);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf("*");
                dir = 'w';
            }
            if (input == 'a') {
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf(" ");
                x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                x = x - 1;
                if (x == 1) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                gotoxy(x, y);
                printf("a");
                gotoxy(x1, y1);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x2, y2);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x3, y3);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf("*");
                dir = 'a';
            }
            if (input == 's') {
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf(" ");
                x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                y = y + 1;
                if (y == 17) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                gotoxy(x, y);
                printf("a");
                gotoxy(x1, y1);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x2, y2);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x3, y3);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf("*");
                dir = 's';
            }
            if (input == 'd') {
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf(" ");
                x4 = x3; x3 = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = x;
                y4 = y3; y3 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = y;
                x = x + 1;
                if (x == 17) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                if (x == x4 && y == y4) {
                    gameover();
                    break;
                }
                gotoxy(x, y);
                printf("a");
                gotoxy(x1, y1);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x2, y2);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x3, y3);
                printf("*");
                gotoxy(x4, y4);
                printf("*");
                dir = 'd';
            }
        }
        if (input == 'p') {
            gameover();
            break;
        }
    }
}
void time_show() {   //아직 미완성(not completed) 
    clock_t s, n;
    s = clock();

    while (1) {
        while (1) {
            n = clock();
            printf("\r");               //커서 왼쪽 끝으로 이동(스테이지의 위치에 따라 수정할 예정)
            printf("Time-\t %d : %d : %d ", ((n - s) / 1000) / 60, ((n - s) / 1000) % 60, (n - s) % 1000);
            if (_kbhit()) break; //키보드 입력이 들어오면 break;
        }

        if (_getch() == 'p') {          //만약 그것이 p이면
            printf("\rTime-\t %d : %d : %d ", ((n - s) / 1000) / 60, ((n - s) / 1000) % 60, (n - s) % 1000);
            _getch();
        }
        else break;

        s = s + (clock() - n);

    }

    printf("\rTime-\t %d : %d : %d ", ((n - s) / 1000) / 60, ((n - s) / 1000) % 60, (n - s) % 1000);

    _getch(); _getch();
    printf("\n\n\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: There are some rare cases where a `goto` is suitable. Your usage is not. You should look up how loopw work in C. If you need a `goto` to create a loop, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is way longer than it needs to be for a minimum example.

Comment: I think you should read about scope of variables, especially in case of "i" in make_stage :) In label2 you use "i" which is not set anywhere. And agree with above comment, goto should be avoided unless you are really C expert and you know what you do ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do not get why you do the `if` statement to check if `i == fruitx` in your `make_stage` function. What do you expect `i` to be at this moment? I would also suggest to add a function call before printing the fruit:

```
//if (i == fruitx)
gotoxy(fruitx, fruity);
printf("f");
```